# Using Reflections to dynamically load all classes in a package

Tags: java, dynamic, classloader

I have a package called "func_commands" that has a bunch of classes that each have the functions "cmd" and "man". I want to be able to load them without specifically stating their names, since I'm using an interface right now, and I want my program to be modular, so that classes can be added or removed by the user, and loaded/unloaded accordingly on the program's next restart.

I've heard that Reflections can do this, but I can't find a working tutorial on how to do it, and I'm an idiot when it comes to documentation. Does anyone know how to do this?

I've been able to use it to find the classes that extend my interface, but I can't figure out how to make it load said classes.

```
    Reflections reflections = new Reflections("func_commands"); //init reflections and point it to the package (I think thats what the string does, I forgot)

    Set<Class<? extends Command>> allClasses = 
            reflections.getSubTypesOf(Command.class); //get the classes from it that extend Commnd
```

How I'm currently loading the classes:

```
for(Command command:CommandArray.commands) {
        command.cmd(e);
        command.man(e);
    };


//meanwhile in CommandArray...
public static Command[] commands = {    
        new ClassA(),
        new ClassB(),
        new ClassC()
};
```

Comment: Do you mean load the classes, or instantiate them? Loading classes isn't something you need to do often in Java.

Comment: @SeverityOne I'm not sure which is which, I'm relatively new to java. What I mean is have them get called on a certain event. I made an edit to the original post for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I want to be able to load them without specifically stating their names, since I'm using an interface right now, and I want my program to be modular, so that classes can be added or removed by the user, and loaded/unloaded accordingly on the program's next restart.**

What you probably mean by this is that you want to be able to instantiate classes and only access their public API via interfaces. This is very good practice.

There are multiple ways to achieve this and you are quite right in noting that reflection is one of them. However, this is quite costly and it involves having to cast the instantiated class. This removes any compile time checks from your program.

Another common practice is to provide a static factory class with methods to instantiate objects. A very good example of this is present in the JDK. `EnumSet` does not have any constructors and only has a static factory. Under the hood, two different classes, namely, `RegularEnumSet` and `JumboEnumSet` are instantiated based on the size of the underlying Enum. You use a similar approach an define classes within the static factory and swap out implementations for different needs.

More information about static factories can be found at: https://dzone.com/articles/constructors-or-static-factory-methods

EDITED: Added a link for reflective class instantiation as well: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/dynamic-class-loading-reloading.html